# I get the variableName is not a function error but it should be

Tags: node.js, express, knex.js

I have this code.And i am getting error that "copied " is not a function.
When i try to access with coppied.getById i am getting copied.getById is not a function
copied.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const copied = require('../domain/copied/index');


router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    copied.getById(req.params.id).then(data => {
        res.json(data);
    }).catch(err => res.json(err))
});


module.exports = router;
```

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var knex = require('../db/knex');
const db = require('../db/knex');

function getById(id) {
    return db.select('*')
      .from('team').where('id', id);
  }

module.exports = { getAll, getById };
```

server.js

```
var copiedController = require("./controllers/copied")
```

Answer (score 0):

Save getById function in a const before being exported.

```
const getById = (id) => {
    return db.select('*')
      .from('team').where('id', id);
  }
```